# A good way to test my Scala/Slick data access object methods

Tags: database, scala, integration-testing, slick

I have a bunch of methods in services that eventually get turned into RPC services such as..

```
CreateNewUser(name,email,etc...)

AppendProductNotes(productId,newNote)

DeleteNoficication(notificationId)
```

and so on...

I'd like to test these methods by doing the following...

1. Insert test data related to the method (if applicable)
2. Run the method
3. Validate the database changed as expected/return variables worked.
4. Reset the database either by rolling back a transaction or rebuilding the test schema

Any suggestions on how to do this in a scala/sbt/slick setup?  I expect to end up with about 100-150 methods that need testing.  Not massive but sizeable for sure.

Comment: Not what you seems to want, but you can also using DB mock, if goal is to validate both your Slick mapping & services based on. When it's fit it has advantage to be more compliant with unit testing than a test DB, and more easy to manage (not setup/clear tasks, not sync of tests to avoid access to same test tables). You can have a look at Acolyte (http://acolyte.eu.org/ ) which is used in Anorm (e.g. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/test/scala/anorm/SqlResultSpec.scala ).

Comment: You can use either an `in-memory` database or `external` database.  For setup, slick `Table` has method `ddl` to help create table, or you just write your own setup sql and execute it. For verifying, I prefer use the return value of method under test or other method related the `data access object it self`.